# Spacing bug in tooltip formatter?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The tooltip formatter seems to be dropping a space in certain situations.

Example at http://jsfiddle.net/tobinibot/FaHNN/1. You can see that in the formatter function, there is a space between the <span> and the <strong> element, but visually, there doesn't appear to be any spacing in the generated tooltip. If you have 2 spaces between the <span> and <strong> elements, then the tooltip looks like what I would expect.

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        return 'this.x + '<br/><span style="color: ' + this.series.color + ';">' + this.series.name + '</span> <strong>' + this.y + '</strong>';
        //                                                                                                    ^ problem spot is here
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to [useHTML from Highcharts API Options Reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.useHTML).

Add `useHTML: true,` under tooltip

```
tooltip: {
            useHTML: true,
            formatter: function() {
                return this.x + '<br/><span style="color: ' + this.series.color + ';">' + this.series.name + '</span> <strong>' + this.y + '</strong>';
            }
        }
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/FaHNN/2/

Comment: Yeah, that works. I was more hoping to just raise this issue with the devs so they are aware of the issue, but I'll accept your answer since it works around the issue (although I already had it working just using 2 spaces).